# When I have a WAR in Tomcat, and it was deployed, if I restart tomcat that WAR will be redeployed?

Tags: apache, http, tomcat, deployment, war

I wan to know if the wars are redeployed on each start/restart of Tomcat.

Or is necessary to delete the deployed folder before restart it?

If that is not redeployed, how can I configure tomcat to deploy with every start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tomcat does not redeploy war files on restart.  Restart is simply turning the underlying service off and back on.  Tomcat does not do the deployment so you will need some other tool (like Jenkins) to automate your deployment.